# VBA loop through all worksheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried following VBA code, where I want to run this code for all available worksheets in active workbook, I think I am making small mistake and as I am beginner I am not able to find it out, please help to fix it up

```
 Sub ProtectFormulas()


 Dim strPassword As String

 Dim ws As Worksheet

 For Each ws In Sheets

 ws.Activate

 .Unprotect

 .Cells.Locked = False

 .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
 .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).FormulaHidden = True

 .Protect AllowDeletingRows:=True

 strPassword = 123456
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strPassword

 Next ws

 End With

 End Sub
```

Any help would be appriciated by word of thanks.

Comment: is there any error while running

Comment: yes, it gives error on `.unprotect` i.e. invalid or unqualified refrance

Comment: with ws missing in code before for each line

Comment: ok, got it, tone of thank you, for putting efforts and taking out time

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 issues with your code:

1. There is no `With` block.
2. The following 2 lines will error if there is no formula in one of the sheets:

   ```
   .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
   .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).FormulaHidden = True
   ```

   Because if there is no formula then `.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` is `Nothing` and therefore nothing has no `.Locked` and no `.FormulaHidden` methods.
3. You mix using `Sheets` and `Worksheets`. Note that those are not the same!

   - `Sheets` is a collection of all type of sheets (worksheets, chart sheets, etc)
   - `Worksheets` is a collection of only type worksheet

   If you declare `Dim ws As Worksheet` and there is for example a chart sheet in your file, then `For Each ws In Sheets` will error because you try to push a chart sheet into a variable `ws` that is defined as `Worksheet` and cannot contain a chart sheet. Be as specific as possible and use `Worksheets` whenever possible in favour of `Sheets`.

The following should work:

```
Option Explicit

'if this is not variable make it a constant and global so you can use it in any procedure
Const strPassword As String = "123456" 

Sub ProtectFormulas()
    'Dim strPassword As String
    'strPassword = "123456"  'remove this here if you made it global

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws 
            .Activate 'I think this is not needed
            .Unprotect Password:=strPassword 'unprotect probably needs your password too or this will not work once the worksheet was protected.
            .Cells.Locked = False
            
            Dim FormulaCells As Range
            Set FormulaCells = Nothing 'initialize (because we are in a loop!)
            On Error Resume Next 'hide error messages (next line throws an error if no forumla is on the worksheet
            Set FormulaCells = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            On Error Goto 0 ' re-enable error reporting! Otherwise you won't see errors if they occur!
            If Not FormulaCells Is Nothing Then 'check if there were formulas to prevent errors if not
                FormulaCells.Locked = True
                FormulaCells.FormulaHidden = True
            End If

            .Protect AllowDeletingRows:=True, Password:=strPassword 
        End With   
    Next ws
 End Sub
```